# Setting up apn_sender for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, resque, apn

I looked at the github but cannot find how I can start sending notification or configure the setting for the apn_sender.

Everytime I start the apn_sender using this gist https://gist.github.com/mariovisic/965976 I get the following error:

bin/apn_sender --environment=development --verbose start

```
/Users/ankur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/apn_sender-2.0.0/lib/apn/sender_daemon.rb:48:in `initialize': invalid option: --environment=development (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from bin/apn_sender:9:in `new'
    from bin/apn_sender:9:in `<main>'
```

How can I setup apn_sender properly or is there any tutorials online on how to do it. I am using Rails 4

Comment: That gist looks way out of date, here's what you're actually calling, [can you make it work](https://github.com/arthurnn/apn_sender/blob/master/lib/apn/sender_daemon.rb)?

Comment: I think I will go with Grocer gem as this is not working out and the documentation is not clear on how to set it up